# Convert month name into number

Tags: excel, date, vba

I have dropdown box with months populated. When a month is selected I would like to then convert it to the month number is there a function that can do this?

Eg. September = 9

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Another way

**Excel Formula**

```
=MONTH(1&A1)
```

**VBA**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim MonthNm As String
    MonthNm = "September"
    Debug.Print Month(DateValue("01 " & MonthNm & " 2012"))
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim MonthNm As String
    MonthNm = "September"
    Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("=MONTH(1&" & Chr(34) & MonthNm & Chr(34) & ")")
End Sub
```

Replace

Answer (score 5):

Try this...

```
 =MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1&"1"))
```

Where `A1` cell contains month name.

Comment: Yesterday I was looking at your profile and when I saw this question I was quite sure you will be the first one to answer... but when it was not responded; I thought let me give it a try. thanks!!

Comment: I already knew the answer but wanted to test all three before I posted (An uncanny habit I must say) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub month()

Dim monthh As Integer

monthh = month(Date)

MsgBox monthh

End Sub
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

another excel formula where `A1` is the cell id with month name:

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(A1&" 1"), "m")
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution didn't work for me (Excel 2010), I had to shorten the month name to 3 characters and add the day number in front of the shortened string.

```
=MONTH(1&LEFT(A1;3))
```

Answer (score -1):

**Another VBA solution**

For the sake of the art in addition to Siddharth's valid answer :-)

```
Sub SampleTM()
  Dim MonthNm$: MonthNm = "September"
  Debug.Print MonthNm2Num(MonthNm)
End Sub

Function MonthNm2Num(ByVal MonthNm) As Long
    MonthNm2Num = Format(CDate(MonthNm & "/1 0"), "m") * 1&
End Function
```