# Convert date string value from U.S. to native Date with current locale <> U.S.?

Tags: datetime, vbscript, locale

As in [Convert month name into number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895228/excel-vba-convert-month-name-into-number), I want to use `DateValue` to create a date from a date string. However, the string I have is guaranteed to be in U.S. format, while the PC executing the code is running on German locales.

Example: `DateValue` fails for `"10 Oct 2013 06:50:19"`, it would succeed for `"10 Okt 2013 06:50:19"` since "October" is "Oktober" in German.

**I.e. I need to get the date from a string in a country-specific date format that is different from the currert locale.**

**How can I do that without hardcoding an English-to-German month names translation table?**

Also, the code should continue to work if the workstation executing the code is reconfigured for a different locale, so I am looking for a way to switch settings temporarily to get the U.S. date via `DateValue`, then switch back to the original setting. Of course, that code should among Windows flavours be portable...

The code currently having this problem is shown below. It tries to get a specific server´s system time by peeking into the http header. It fails if the current (short) month name in English is different in German.

```
Public Function GetServerTimeFromUrl (ByVal Url,ByRef DT)

    Dim HttpRequest: Set HttpRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp")
    HttpRequest.Open "GET" , Url, false
    HttpRequest.Send

    Dim Result: Result=(HttpRequest.Status = 200)
    If Result then

        Dim DateS: DateS=HttpRequest.getResponseHeader ("Date")
        DateS=Right (DateS,Len (DateS)-InStr (DateS,",")-1)
        ' DateS has weekday removed

        DateS=Left (DateS,InStrRev (DateS," ")-1)
        ' DateS has timezone removed

        ' DateS now holds something like "09 Sep 2013 11:49:54" 
        Dim ServerTimeGMT: ServerTimeGMT=DateValue (DateS)+TimeValue (DateS)

        Dim Delta: Delta=CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\ActiveTimeBias")    
        ' Delta now holds "skew" value for time zone including DST
        DT=DateAdd("n", -Delta,ServerTimeGMT)
        Result=true
    End If
    GetServerTimeFromUrl=Result
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GetLocale` and `SetLocale` to change the locale:

This should work on a German system with a US date

```
option explicit

dim currentLocale
currentLocale = GetLocale()

SetLocale 1033       ' 1033 is the EN-US locale
msgbox datevalue("9 Oct 2013 06:50:19")
' Output: 10/9/2013

' Put back the original locale
SetLocale currentLocale
```

Or the other way around; a German date on a US system

```
SetLocale 1031       ' 1031 is the German locale
msgbox datevalue("9 Okt 2013 06:50:19")
' Output: 09.10.2013
```

Comment: Oh sure! It´s as simple as that. Thank you.

Comment: Just [knowing which screw to turn](http://calvinconaway.com/2007/05/27/knowing-which-screw-to-turn/), and that is why sites as SO are so great!