# VBA equivalent to VBScript's 'SetLocale' function?

Tags: vba, excel

To summarize my problem, I'm currently having the exact same issue as the person from [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289265/convert-date-string-value-from-u-s-to-native-date-with-current-locale-u-s). I'm trying to parse a US date into an Excel sheet that has German as default and gives me a type mismatch on most of the dates because of it.

`SetLocale` sounded like the perfect solution to my issue, but after a minute of further research I discovered that `GetLocale` and `SetLocale` are apparently **not** supported in VBA.

It *sort of* worked when I assigned the parsed date to a String variable (I end up with a column using either `MM/DD/YYYY` or `DD/MMM/YYYY` format depending on whether or not I had a type mismatch, as long as I use `On Error Resume`), but I need them in a `MM/DD/YYYY` date type/format in order to compare all the parsed dates to a specific date in another cell (attempting to determine if the site has had any updates since the date entered in the specific cell).

I've also tried doing `TimeStamp = Format(TimeStamp, "MM/DD/YYYY")` (TimeStamp being a variable containing the parsed date), but it doesn't seem to be working- most likely due to the type mismatch error.

If anyone knows a VBA equivalent of the `SetLocale` function used in the linked question for me to try out, I would greatly appreciate it. If there isn't any, I'll be happy to amend my question and add my current code here to try and hammer out a solution together.

Thank you for your time and your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know they are all in US format, you can use a function like this:

```
Function ConvertUSDate(sDate) As Date
    ConvertUSDate = Evaluate("DATEVALUE(""" & sDate & """)")
End Function
```