# Date Range Visual Basic Script Not Working as Expected?

Tags: date, vbscript, date-range

I'm passing my variables in the following order:
FileEndDate StartDateRange EndDateRange

```
FileEndDate = 10/11/2019
StartDateRange = 01/04/2019
EndDateRange = 30/04/2019
```

However, my code returns 'True', despite the fact that 10/11/2019 should not be in the date range of 01/04/2019 -> 30/04/2019.

```
If (WScript.Arguments.Item(0) >= WScript.Arguments.Item(1)) And (WScript.Arguments.Item(0) <= WScript.Arguments.Item(2)) Then
   WScript.Stdout.Writeline "True"
Else    
   WScript.Stdout.Writeline "False"
End If
```

Comment: You are comparing strings. If you want to compare dates, you need to convert the strings to date, eg using `CDate`.

Comment: Sorry for the tag discrepancies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing strings, `"10/11/2019" > "01/04/2019"` and `"10/11/2019" < "30/04/2019"`.

You may want to work with dates instead, **or** rewrite the strings to make sure a simple string comparison will work (YYYY/MM/DD)

The latter can be done this way :

```
dim FileEndDate : FileEndDate = "10/11/2019"
dim StartDateRange : StartDateRange = "01/04/2019"
dim EndDateRange : EndDateRange = "30/04/2019"

function ReformatDate(sInputDate)
    dim aResult
    aResult = Split(sInputDate, "/")
    ReformatDate = aResult(2) & "/" & aResult(1) & "/" & aResult(0)
end function

FileEndDate = ReformatDate(FileEndDate)
StartDateRange = ReformatDate(StartDateRange)
EndDateRange = ReformatDate(EndDateRange)

If (FileEndDate >= StartDateRange) And (FileEndDate <= EndDateRange) Then
   MsgBox "True"
Else    
   MsgBox "False"
End If
```

This outputs `"False"`

---

Note that this doesn't check the initial format of the strings. You may need to write your own check function to ensure that it won't crash.

Comment: Why not [just use `SetLocale` to set the current regional settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19312026/692942) for a particular LCID then use `CDate()` to convert it to a `Date` variable?

Comment: @Lankymart using date objects was my first idea, but I'm not used to handle dates in VBS and I prefered handling strings to allow an alphanum comparison. Feel free to edit my answer if you want to add details concerning this way

Answer (score -2):

You are comparing strings and not dates.

Let's try this: convert your date strings as date types, then compare them:

```
Dim myDateFormat As String = "dd/MM/yyyy"
Dim date0 As Date = Date.ParseExact(WScript.Arguments.Item(0).ToString(), myDateFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim date1 As Date = Date.ParseExact(WScript.Arguments.Item(1).ToString(), myDateFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim date2 As Date = Date.ParseExact(WScript.Arguments.Item(2).ToString(), myDateFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

If (date0 >= date1) And (date0 <= date2) Then
   WScript.Stdout.Writeline "True"
Else    
   WScript.Stdout.Writeline "False"
End If
```

Also, using this could help avoid ulterior mistakes:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
```

Have fun!

Comment: This is not valid VBScript.

Comment: Tags have been updated since I posted this.

Comment: I'm aware of that, since I was the one correcting the tags. However, the title of the question clearly stated "Visual Basic Script" from the start, and the code is obviously VBScript too.