# Inverse of the MonthName() - Function?

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a month number. By typing in the immediate editor **MonthName(11,True)** I get the result **NOV**. What would be the inverse of this function? e.g. I've got SEP and I want by typing 
function(SEP) the number 9 as an Output

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895228/excel-vba-convert-month-name-into-number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim MonthNm As String
    MonthNm = "September"
    Debug.Print Month(DateValue("01 " & MonthNm & " 2014"))
End Sub
```

or in small:

```
=MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1&"9"))
```

Also check 
[How to convert month name to number in Excel?](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1549-excel-convert-month-name-to-number.html#a1)