# Converting Month name to a 3 letter abbreviation

Tags: vba, excel

Anybody knows how to convert a month name into 3 letter abbreviation? For example, if the month is September, then it should return Sep only. I have been searching in the net but unfortunate enough to have the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with below

```
Sub test()
    Dim a As String
    a = Format("11/10/2015", "MMM")
    MsgBox a
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub test()
    Dim a As String
    a = Format(Now(), "MMM")
    MsgBox a
End Sub
```

if you have the month name as variable then

```
Sub test()
    Dim a As String
    a = "February"
    MsgBox Mid(a, 1, 3)
End Sub
```

Comment: What if I have a variable that equates to the name of the month?

Comment: @ramedju: `Mid(monthNameVariable, 1, 3)`

Comment: @shahkalpesh what is the use of MID ? and 1 and 3?

Comment: @ramedju: `Mid` is a function that takes a string and extracts part of it. In this case, it is extract 3 characters from position 1.

Answer (score 1):

What will always work is to make your own function, e.g.:

```
Function Month2Mon(month) As String
    Select Case LCase(month)
    Case "january": Month2Mon = "Jan"
    Case "february": Month2Mon = "Feb"
    ...
End Function
```

Comment: Too tricky?? What do you mean? Will always do as you want. You can change `month` for a number if you like

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim MonthName As String
    MonthName = "September"
    MsgBox Format(DateValue("01 " & MonthName & " 2012"), "MMM")
End Sub
```

This solution is derived from @SiddhartRout's answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895228/convert-month-name-into-number).