# Excel VBA save as name "MONTH" converted to number (two digits)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new here and also in VBA. I'm trying to figure out to export active sheet to new workbook (just values) and save it as specific name where part of the name has to be month converted to two digits format. 
To be more specific there is a month name in "D4". I need to use this month in the name of the new workbook but converted to two digits format.

```
With ActiveSheet
                ActiveSheet.Range("A1:M40").Copy
                    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
                    With NewBook
                        NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                        Dim LMonth As Integer
                        NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("D4") & "_" & Range("I2") & "_" & " FLA"
                    End With
          End With
```

Here is the full code which prints out the sheet as pdf and then exports the sheet to new workbook:

```
Private Sub Print_PDF_Click()
With ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
       ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & " " & Range("I2") & " FLA" _
       , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
       :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
          With ActiveSheet
                ActiveSheet.Range("A1:M40").Copy
                    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
                    With NewBook
                        NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                        Dim LMonth As Integer
                        NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Format(Range("D4"),"mm") & "_" & Range("I2") & "_" & " FLA"
                    End With
          End With
    MsgBox "PDF successfully created!"
End With 
End Sub
```

Please help!

Comment: As in [Convert month name into number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895228/convert-month-name-into-number)?

Comment: It there really the name of the month in the cell or does the cell contain a date and is formatted to display the name of a month?

Comment: "D4" contains Month name as "January, February ...etc." formatted as date. So if there will be "May" I need "05" in the name of new workbook.

Comment: Still not clear to me: If you select the cell with the month: what is displayed in the data entry field at the top? A date? Then the *content* of the field is a date. In this case, simply use `format(Range("D4"), "MM")`

Comment: "MM" saves it as month name not as two digits ("January" instead of "01").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the VBA equivalent of @asantaballa's odd looking but great Excel formula..

Change your `NewBook.SaveAs` line's Filename to

```
 Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Format(DateValue(Range("D4") & " 1"), "mm") & "_" & Range("I2") & "_" & " FLA"
```

This takes the month in `D4`, appends it with `" 1"` to make it look like a real date and then uses `DateValue` to convert it to a Date value which we can then use `Format` to derive the number from.

So `AUGUST` in cell D4

becomes `AUGUST 1` by appending " 1"

which becomes `01/08/2001` using `DateValue` function

which is formatted to `mm` to produce **`08`**.

Comment: It says "Syntax Error". Are you sure there is ampersand between ("D4") & " 1") ?

Comment: You did only change everything **AFTER** `NewBook.SaveAs` yes?

Comment: This will produce a filename such as `"path\05_[contents of I2]_ FLA"` - did you want that space there? Did you not want to end with `.xlsx` or similar?

Comment: The Syntax error is now in the previous part to create PDF. So disabled this part of code and the export works like a charm! Thanks a lot @CLR!

Answer (score 1):

Looks kind of funny, but try

```
=TEXT(MONTH(DATEVALUE(D4 & "1")),"00")
```

http://www.exceltip.com/tips/converting-month-name-to-a-number-in-excel-2010-2013.html

Comment: I don't want to convert "D4". I just need to use "D4" value in the name of new workbook but converted to two digits format.

Comment: Or for `05` rather than `5`, `=TEXT(MONTH(DATEVALUE(D4 & "1")),"00")`

Comment: Thanks, @CLR, missed the two digits. Edited.

Comment: The code doesn't convert D4 as such, it converts the value in D4.... at the moment it's just text - Excel doesn't understand that it's a date just that it's some text - could just as well be "Nuficek" in there.  Now, `DateValue` turns a text string into a date if it can - `DateValue("Nuficek 1")` will return an error, but `DateValue("August 1")` will return `01/08/2018` which can then be formatted to show the month number - `8`, or as @CLR added `08`.